# Input Box Resets Page on Enter Instead of Running Function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

So I've read a lot about this but none of the resources I looked at solved my
specific issue.

**Goal:** When text is input into the box and enter is hit, I want the function `$("#search").click();` to run

**Problem**: Instead, it seems to refresh the page.

I had a similar problem with the button, but that was solved with `type="button"`. I've tried changing the type of the input to `submit, text, search`, but no dice.

I tried
setting `onsubmit="return false;"` in the `input` tag and the parent `form` tag and all combinations.

The code for the function:

```
$("#searchInput").keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which == 13){
                    $("#search").click();
                };
        });
```

It is outside of the scope of the ajax request preceding it. I tried `keyCode` as well.
**EDIT: minified && EDIT#2** Previous edit broke the click functionality: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bushido/ypxm0ukL/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sav1q3wt/1/

The things I did:

1) Moved the `keypress` event handler out of `onclick`
2) Changed `onclick` to `submit` and added `e.preventDefault();`

Edit:

`preventDefault()` prevents default behaviour ex: redirecting after clicking a submit button

Comment: ah beautiful, thank you very much Device. It works now

Answer (score 1):

If you move the keypress handler out of onclick, and add preventDefault() to the keypress handler, it should work as desired:

```
$("#searchInput").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#search").click();
     };
 });
```

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chestercharles/ypxm0ukL/12/

Comment: That is odd.. I could have sworn it wasn't working on enter yesterday.. my mistake chester

Comment: I think what happened was was i was just mashing the board when inputting a string to test and it was just coming up with no results and I thought it was broken...

Comment: No worries, @Danny. Thanks for taking another look.